# Creating diagrams

Tags: discussion, images

I am fed up of using MS paint for creating diagrams and posting images on our board , do you have any application which will me to create diagrams easily . which must be portable or is there any website to design diagrams.

somebody please edit my tags ..

Thanks

Comment: The FAQ says: "Do not post off-topic questions" - Then you make a question and name it: "Off Topic Question". Because the FAQ is for weak people! XD

Comment: For example this questions seems useful: [Software for drawing geometry diagrams](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1985/software-for-drawing-geometry-diagrams) and [Looking for a Drawing Program](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/105754/looking-for-a-drawing-program). Maybe if you search in questions tagged [tag:math-software], you can find several other similar questions.

Comment: On a related note, I'd love to see tikz support on MathJax.  (I ain't holdin' my breath for that one, though.)

Comment: @Alexander: There is a 3rd-party plugin called XyJax which is a xy support for MathJax. It's unlikely to be assimilated into the main code, or get supported by SE anytime soon methinks.

Comment: I'll add link to [TeX Community Polls](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/1592/9954) from TeX.SE. You can see there what software (La)TeX users prefer for creating various kinds of diagrams.

Comment: Another related question: [Creating simple graphs](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1819)

Answer (score 12):

In [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/246113/752) answer I posted the following plot created in $\mathrm{\LaTeX}$, using the [`TikZ` package](http://ftp.eq.uc.pt/software/TeX/graphics/pgf/base/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf).

[image]

Or a contour such as this one

[image]

Comment: The certainly isn't the quickest solution, but it allows you the most control. I wish I had learned to use tikz much earlier...

Comment: @user1729 You are right! I only know how to draw  simple plots and contours.

Comment: I had to draw a "bouquet of circles" once, which was pretty difficult. I wanted to draw a graph with a single vertex and two loop edges, and then some dots to signify that there were some edges I hadn't put in. There were arrows and labels everywhere! It took me a long, long time to figure out how to do it, but my tikz is certainly better as a result!

Answer (score 8):

You could use:

- Geogebra
- Mathematica
- Wolfram Alpha
- SageMath

It depends on the depth of the question. But for the questions you are making, I guess Geogebra is enough.

Answer (score 3):

When in need for diagrams used in category theory and some closely related fields, [Presheaf.com](http://presheaf.com) can help you out.

I was pointed to it by Martin in [this comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/398609/cocartesian-squares-in-the-category-of-abelian-groups#comment853117_398683).

Answer (score 2):

I use Microsoft Visio to draw contours.  It's not ideal, but the elements are all there and I use it for my everyday work.

Answer (score 2):

Usually, as you may find out from my answers; I use my handy works or use Maple 17. Sometimes, I really need a Blackboard.

Answer (score 1):

I use Powerpoint, Excel, Mathematica, and CAD software.

Other packages that seem pretty good (but which I don't use) are Inkscape and GIMP.

I don't understand the "portable" comment. Regardless of which package software I use, I typically just grab a screen shot to post here. So the file format used by the software package is irrelevant.